# Not able to generate string from complex regular expression with Fare

Tags: c#, .net, regex, fare

I am using Fare library https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare/ to generate a random string from regular expression. Up until now, it has been working properly.

What I wanted now is
"The Password must have a minimum/maximum of 8 characters, including one special character, atleast 1 digit and atleast capital letter."
Special characters allowed are !#$%^&*()=,.

for that, I have created the expression

```
 ^((?=.\d)(?=.[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,8})$
```

But it is not generating valid expression
Please check what's the problem

I am generating the regular expression with:

```
var secret = new Xeger(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["expression"]).Generate();
Console.WriteLine(secret);
```

I have updated the pattern requirement

Comment: Most probably Fare regex does not support lookaheads. Split the conditions into simpler regexes.

Comment: Not that expert Wiktor in regex :(
Can someone help me in it?

Comment: But you already have that all: `\d` - at least a digit. `[A-Z]` - at least 1 uppercase letter... The length can be checked by `string.Length`.

Comment: I am using above expression to generate random password

Comment: What you try is not 'generate a regular expression', but rather: 'generating strings that match a regular expression'. Please be clear.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Xeger is known for that it can't generate any string if the regex contains lookarounds. While it generates examples, add conditions "manually" using the patterns in your lookaheads.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you help me out in updated expression

Comment: No, I cannot rewrite Xeger. It does not support the feature you need.

Comment: I were thinking that we can have an alternative expression which doesn't have lookahead but validating the our required criteria.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have simplified the pattern requirement. can someone help me out how i can create that pattern

Comment: Forget about these kinds of regexps. Just generate any strings of 8 chars length. Then check if there is a capital letter, if it does, check if it contains a digit, then check if it contains a special char. If all these are present take the string, else discard, generate the next 8 char string, and go on.

Comment: Wiktor what my application is doing is maintaining a secret expression as per requirement. I were just maintaining a regular express. And generating the secret at some time on base of that expression via xerger library. it is working perfectly fine till now. Now first time we are struck in it. i am even ready to simplify the required complexity of total 8 characters password with one digit, one Capital character and one special character.

Comment: My application even have functionality of client desired secret change which should match the regular expression.

Comment: @KamranShahid I answered your other question (now deleted) because I hadn't seen this one. In my answer, I said that I wasn't sure if the library you're using supports Lookaheads (I couldn't find any info about it because you mistyped its name "xerger"). Anyway, since the fact that it doesn't support Lookarounds has already been established, there's nothing really you can do. Like Wiktor said, if Xeger doesn't support what you need, what is there to be done? Just because Xeger worked for you with other patterns, doesn't mean it will work with every other pattern (it has limitations, remember?)

Comment: So, take a step back and start thinking of other solutions (other than regex). I think Wiktor's suggestion is great, why do you not want to give it a try?

Comment: Will look into workaround as well but it looks like need quite a bit of effort as in my product i am only maintaining this regex in a persistent storage and on it's basis i am doing lots of thing.without disturbing current procedure For some app demo i like to check if i can introduce a pattern where i can have a 8 length password with one digit, one capital letter and some allowed special character which works with xeger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Fare doesn't support lookaheads, then you may instead try using a different regex expression devoid of any such lookaheads:

^([0-9])([A-Z])([!@#%*()$?+-])([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})$

So this regex expression can be used for validating passwords but we would then be restricting user to input first a digit, second a capital letter, third a special character with rest being a mix of alphanumeric chars.